# Return <motion> character from Python function in <expr> mapping

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript-python

I am trying to return this `:GrepperAck ''<Left>` from a Python function and use it in the following mapping

```
def invoke_search_command():
  return ":GrepperAck ''<Left>"
```

```
:nnoremap <expr> <leader>f py3eval('invoke_search_command()')
```

But the `<Left>` is printed literally like `:GrepperGit ''<Left>`.

But if I use `:nnoremap <expr> <leader>f py3eval('invoke_search_command()') . '<Left>'`, it works. I tried escaping the returned string like `":GrepperAck ''\<Left>"`, but it is still getting printed literally. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BLayer Sorry, that was my bad.

Comment: Did you see my updated answer?

Comment: I am just checking that out. My bad, I am not getting any notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need the backslash version `\<Left>`. Is use of `py3eval` necessary? Unless you need to translate data structures from Python to Vim or something it would be better to return a straight string. You need to make sure the string `:GrepperAck ''\<Left>` is passed literally to the command line. Then it will be processed as an expression due to `<expr>`.

I don't have a Python installation but I can demonstrate the fundamental workings without it. Given...

```
func! Foo()
    return ":GrepperAck ''\<Left>"
endfunc
```

And this mapping...

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>f Foo()
```

Then when I enter leader key and <kbd>f</kbd> this is what I'll see on the command line..

```
:GrepperAck ''
```

...and the cursor will be inside the quotes.

If you must use `py3eval` then one thing you might try is to wrap that in a `string()` function call.

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>f string(py3eval(..))
```

---

**Update:** In retrospect the reason `\<Left>` doesn't work is almost certainly because the parsing of the mapping occurs in a certain order, i.e. the phase that substitutes actual keys for `<xxx>` tokens occurs before any external programs are executed. I haven't confirmed this by looking at the Vim source code or anything but as a veteran software developer I can tell you that it's a solid theory. It wouldn't make much sense for the parser to have multiple passes with `<xxx>` resolution nor, generally speaking, to make such a pass over external (non-Vim originated) runtime data.

Can anything be done? Well, I thought that substituting the actual key code would do the trick....

```
def invoke_search_command():
    return ":GrepperAck ''<C-V><Left>"
```

That means rather than type `\<Left>` you actually enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow key).  (For me the combo comes out looking like `^[OD`.) Unfortunately, I'm getting an error: `Not an editor command: GrepperAck ''`. *But* I know I'm on the right track because if I replace <kbd>←</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (commonly the same function as the backspace key) then the cursor is actually moved on the resulting GrepperAck command line (erasing the last `'` as expected).

So why isn't the left arrow key code working?  Dunno. It might be that we can substitute something else in the terminal codes but that's a stretch and getting into possibly non-portable behavior. I'll play around with that for a bit but unfortunately, unless your system behaves differently than mine (try it out) I believe the ultimate answer to your question is "this is not possible".

Comment: I will try the string function call and let you know if this works, and accept this answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @RajaRaviVarma Thank you. If it doesn't work and there are any additional details that might help let me know. I like to see a question/answer through to the end if I'm able.

Comment: Wrapping the whole expression with `string()` throws `Unknown mark` error. Sorry that didn't work.

Comment: I also tried returning the value of the `py3eval(..)` function, from another vim function. The result was the same, it printed the literal `\<Left>` instead of moving the cursor left..

Comment: @RajaRaviVarma Okay. I'm fairly busy right now but I'll investigate when I get a chance. Just to be sure does my fundamental (non-python) example work as described for you? That'll help rule out anything configuration/environment related.

Comment: Yup, the  pure vim function worked fine.

Comment: When I try the `<Ctrl-V><Left>`, I get `^[OD` just like you said. For me it opens the quickfix and inserts the `D` character in my last cursor position. But you explanation makes sense and I will accept it. Thanks for all the work.

Comment: @RajaRaviVarma You're welcome. Thanks for accepting it. Wish there was a better outcome.